# XAMPP / error is first "mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045):", then "mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1049)"

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I've got a MySQL database connection running fine in the production version of my site, but I recently installed XAMPP on my machine and I can't connect using the same credentials. When I use the same credentials I use for the production version of my code, I get the below error:

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'dsussman'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Even though I'm 100% sure that the username and password I typed were both correct AND that I had all permissions granted to that username, I updated to the below anyway:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "master";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

Upon doing this, I saw that my error is now:

> Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'master'

Why isn't this working locally? The database 'master' definitely exists and that's the correct spelling. Appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Can you login to MySQL in another way and run the query `SHOW DATABASES:`?

Comment: in PHPMyAdmin, results are `master` and `information_schema`

Comment: Are you running a separate instance of MySQL or are you running the instance installed by XAMPP?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but I don't think I have a separate instance of MySQL running. I've restarted the MySQL XAMPP server a few times though, with no luck.

Comment: Try changing the database to `information_schema` and see if you get the same error.

Comment: You can stop the XAMPP mysql and can check again if you get different error or same error. Alternatively, you can also run query: "Show databases" after making successful connection.